# hiding certain fields in html page to use for header/footer in print layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been making print layouts and I understand how to use @media print tags. What i am trying to do is to use a different header/footer for my print layouts than on the actual page. I am putting the different header/footer on the original page but i am having an issue trying to hide the additional fields on the actual page itself.

HTML:

```
<div class=different_header>Different content</div>
<div class=different_footer>Different content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.different_header, .different_footer {
    display: none;
}

@media print{
.different_header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
.different_Footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

I've tried this....but nothing so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you told it to hide, it won't show unless you tell it to show itself:

```
.different_header, .different_footer {
    display: none;
}

@media print{
    .different_header, .different_footer {
        display: block; /* <------------------- HERE */
    }
    .different_header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    .different_footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well whats actually happening is the header and the footer will show up on the actual page and not hide like its supposed to

Comment: @zomdar, no, with this code, the header & footer should hide when on the page, and show when printed.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice :x